# Makefile for C++ project - dependency generation

Tags: c++, makefile

I would like some input on the Makefile I'm using for my C++ project. It is my first Makefile and I learned how to do what I want through various readings on the web. The directory structure is as follows :

```
project directory
|___ src/ (source files)
|___ include/ (header files)
|___ tests/ (source files each containing "int main(int argc, char **argv)"
|___ build/ (object files and dependency files)
|___ bin/ (compiled programs)
|___ Makefile
```

The main reason I'm asking for input is that recently I did some changes, including adding a member to one of my classes and this caused my program to crash with segfaults ; it turns out that doing a `make clean` and recompiling from scratch resolved the problem as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098847).

Apparently the automatic dependency generation failed in some way and some parts of my program were not recompiled when I changed the header... At least that is what I understand. So if the dependency generation (g++ -MMD) is not done right I would like to know how to improve it. Here is the Makefile :

```
# Makefile 

# Compiler
CXX      := -g++
# Compiler flags
CXXFLAGS := -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -g -O0

# Library flags
LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/lib -lstdc++ -lm
# Librairy flags for petsc
LDFLAGS_PETSC = ... # long list of library flags
LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS_PETSC)

# List of include directories
# use -isystem to supress warnings for this folder
INCLUDE := -Iinclude/ -isysteminclude/lepton/ -Iinclude/gauss-legendre-quadrature/
INCLUDE_PETSC := -I/home/intendant/software/petsc/include \
                 -I/home/intendant/software/petsc/arch-linux2-cxx-debug/include
INCLUDE += $(INCLUDE_PETSC)
# Include boost if downloaded from boost.org instead of installed through apt-get
# INCLUDE_BOOST := -I/opt/boost_1_67_0/
# INCLUDE += $(INCLUDE_BOOST)

# List of source files 
SRC_DIR := src
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) \
           $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/lepton/*.cpp) \
           $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/gauss-legendre-quadrature/*.cpp)
# NOTE: gauss_legendre renamed from .c to .cpp after download

# List of source files for tests and mains
MAIN_DIR := tests
MAIN_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(MAIN_DIR)/*.cpp)

# List of executables
TARGET_DIR := bin
TARGETS = $(MAIN_SOURCES:$(MAIN_DIR)/%.cpp=$(TARGET_DIR)/%.out)
TARGET_NAMES = $(MAIN_SOURCES:$(MAIN_DIR)/%.cpp=%)

# List of objects files for src/ and tests/ files
OBJ_DIR  := build
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
MAIN_OBJECTS := $(MAIN_SOURCES:$(MAIN_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

# Create variable containing list of dependencies (generated by gcc)
DEP = $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)

# Remove warnings when building lepton library
build/lepton/%.o: CXXFLAGS += -w

# Default target should be cfm
main: build $(TARGET_DIR)/cfm.out
# Build all executables
all: build $(TARGETS) 

# Include all .d files
-include $(DEP)

# Make object files from source files (-MMD generates dependencies .d files)
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -MMD -o $@ -c $<

# Make object files from main source files (-MMD generates dependencies .d files)
$(MAIN_OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(MAIN_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -MMD -o $@ -c $<

# Link object files with appropriate main to create app
$(TARGETS): $(TARGET_DIR)/%.out: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o $(OBJECTS) 
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo "Linking "$@"..."
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Convenience rule to type "make program" instead of "make bin/program.out"
$(TARGET_NAMES): %: $(TARGET_DIR)/%.out

.PHONY: all build clean debug release main $(TARGET_NAMES)

build:
    @mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g  -O0
debug: all

release: CXXFLAGS += -O2
release: all

clean:
    -@rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/*
    -@rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)/*
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question falls into _code not working as intended_ category, which it strictly off-topic here. That said, I strongly recommend to roll out an explicit `%.d: %.cpp` (with `-MMD` and _without_ `-c`) rule.

Comment: in case you just want the task to be done consider using https://github.com/igagis/prorab